# How to get indent on a new line

Tags: html, css

[image: Overflow text wont indent]

I am trying to get the text to indent whenever it is pushed to a new line (due to the screen resizing).
I have been fiddling at it for a while now but stuff like: display:block doesnt seem to do it for me.
Does anyone know how I can make the text indent on each new line?

I am using the following HTML code:

```
<ul class="sortable ui-sortable list-group">
    @foreach (UIBookmark b in Model.Bookmarks)
    {
        <li class="bookmark-card ui-sortable-handle" id="@b.Id">
            <form class="form-button" action="/Api/Bookmarks/@b.Id" method="DELETE">
            <a href="#" class="link-submit">
            <span class="ql glyphicon glyphicon-star" />
            </a>
            </form>

            <span>@Quick.LinkForLinkable(Html, b.Target)</span>
        <p class="text-muted revision-date">&#8195;&#8195;&#8195;<i class="glyphicon-glyphicon-chevron-right"></i>@b.Target.GetTypeDisplay()</p>
    </li>
    }
</ul>
```

Comment: It depends on your current HTML code

Comment: you should share the HTML and CSS code for the list, without it, we cannot help much

Comment: check alternate approach below. uses pseudo class. @Teije

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do it, among them :

- Table

```css
td {
  border: blue solid 2px;
  max-width: 160px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>★</td>
      <td>contract manufacturing companies</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

- Flexbox

```css
.container {
  max-width: 180px;
  display: flex;
}
.container div {
  border: blue solid 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>★</div>
  <div>contract manufacturing companies</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flexbox is our lord and savior :) Everything complicated to obtain and dodgy in classic CSS (float, display:inline, margin-bottom, etc.) is a breeze with Flexbox.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply margin-bottom on your star element. That should help

Answer (score 0):

You can add the star image using pseudo class `:before` and make the `li` display `flex`. Outer container need not be flex.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 180px;
}
.container li {
  list-style: none;
  color: #0095ff;
  display: flex;
}
.container li:before {
  content: "\2605";
}
label{  
  padding-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li>
    <label>contract manufacturing companies</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```